# PhpStorm - error when typing in Vietnamese

Tags: macos, syntax-error, phpstorm, typing

[image: PhpStorm - Error type]

When I'm typing, the error occurred as shown on the picture.

The contents jumbled when typing.

I use MacOS. Oh, when i trying to move the cursor using the next button on my keyboard, the error does not occur anymore. It only error when moving with the mouse.

Help me!

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: maybe, I don't know @@

Comment: @NhaNK Did you setting files encoding as UTF-8?

Comment: @LongPham Yes, i have already setting UTF-8.

Comment: @NhaNK Are you using MacOS? Can you trying to move the cursor using the next button on your keyboard and let me know what happens? Thank you!

Comment: @LongPham Oh, when i trying to move the cursor using the next button on my keyboard, the error does not occur anymore. It only error when moving with the mouse. ???

Comment: @NhaNK If you're using MacOS. I believe it was a bug of Mac platform. Try to change your input source as `Vietnamese/Simple Telex` maybe solve your problem.

Comment: @LongPham I have trying use Vietnamese/Simple Telex, but no effect.

Comment: @KhacNha has the problem been solved now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: macOS percussion error.
Do not use Vietnamese percussion of the system, but use this:
https://www.trankynam.com/gotv/macos/